# DocuSign: Use dropdown selection to display associated text

Tags: docusignapi

We have a form we use to send out to new clients. On it we ask them to choose an Investment Objective which is displayed as a dropdown with these options: Conservative, Moderate, Aggressive.  Below the dropdown is a text "area" where we want to display some descriptive text about what the client selects.

What I currently have working is 3 textboxes (ConText, ModText, and AggText). I prefill these boxes with values I get from our database (in case the descriptions change) before I send the request. On the template, these textboxes are stacked on top of each other in the text "area" below the dropdown and I have conditional logic which displays the correct textbox based on the dropdown selection.

This is working, but it seems a bit kludgy.  Question 1: Is there a better way?

Problems:  We've had several clients report while they can see the text when filling out the form and it changes when they select different objectives, when they receive the completed document, the text area is blank.  I tested on my Sandbox account and it works perfectly.  The Production template is the same one we use on my Sandbox account, so they *should* work the same.  I've compared downloads of the 2 templates (JSON) and other than GUID differences, they appear the same in regards to this issue.

Question 2: What could cause this difference in the completed documents sent out by our Production account and my Sandbox account?  (I've tried to have them configured the same as much as possible).

If you have any questions or need more information, please let me know.

thanks,
randy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to recreate the error.  When the Client is filling out the DocuSign form, if they DO NOT change the initial value of the dropdown, when the form is submitted, the text description will be blank.  And this only occurs with a dropdown that is "linked" to a textbox to display associated text. That's a scenario I failed to test.

I asked DocuSign for some assistance and after sending them my template and an envelope request, they were able to quickly uncover the problem.

The dropdowns I generally use are just lists of strings where the display value is also the value of the dropdown.  Therefore, when I prefill the envelope request, I just set the string value I pull from the database as the string to be initially displayed.  And this is the first time I've used a dropdown to enable another control.

In this instance, I wanted the selected value to be a 2-letter code we use since that's what will be going back into the database.  So, the dropdown has an Option (such as, Conservative) which is displayed to the Client and a Value (such as CN) which is returned when the envelope results are processed.

I did what I have done in the past -- initialized the dropdown with the display string value. And that worked as long as the Client changed the initial selection. This is because the conditional rules I created used the Value (2-letter code) as the trigger value.  If the initial selection isn't changed, nothing gets triggered by setting the Option instead of the Value.

By changing the code to initialize the dropdown using the Value code, it all works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Use the eSignature settings app to check the value of the **Sending Settings**

`When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field for all recipients`

I think you want it unchecked. Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I checked both my Sandbox account and the Production account, and both have this setting unchecked as you suggested.  I'm now getting reports that this might have been a 1-time bug.  My boss ran a dummy request through the Production system and it worked perfectly.  I think this is now a "let's wait and see if this happens again" situation.  It might be something weird this particular end user is doing.  Thanks again!